# Hadoop - Split file by lines count

Tags: scala, file, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a file on my hdfs with 320000000 rows,
And I want to split it into 4 files with max 100000000 rows in file.
How can I split the file by number of lines?

I tried to re-partition by 11, but the partition is too big. Can I solve it by command? Or by another way in Scala spark?

Comment: Well...... No there is no "command" which splits a file with 101 rows into 11 files with max 10 rows.

Comment: If you have a file to start with, no other processing to do, and you just want to split the file into other files, this is not a good use of Spark. Just run a trivial script on the file. On Unix, the split command will do it http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: yeah but this file is on my hdfs, i can not run normal unix commands on it only hdfs commands

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and then write into 11 files.

Comment: if it was on a regular file it was easy, I need it for hdfs file